# How to resize picutureboxes in a for loop

Tags: vb.net

I needed help resizing pictureboxes in a for loop
i dont want to resize picturebox1, then resize picturebox2 etc

```
Sub MakePiece()
    Dim PieceHeight, PieceWidth As Integer
    Dim PuzzleImage As New Bitmap(ChosenFilename)
    ' dividing the dimensions by 18
    PieceHeight = PuzzleImage.Height / 18
    PieceWidth = PuzzleImage.Width / 18
    ' resizing the puzzlepieces1-9 and refreshing
    For index = 1 To 9
        PictureBoxPuzzlePiece(index).Width = PieceWidth
        PictureBoxPuzzlePiece(index).height = PieceHeight
    Next
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

All pictureboxes 1-9 get resized

Comment: Is there a way to format "PictureBoxPuzzlePiece" with index?

Comment: Isn't that what you do inside your loop?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you just want to re-size picturebox 2, 4, 6 and 8?

```
for index = 2 to 9 step 2
```

would do the trick, surely?

If not, can you define more precisely how you want to decide which are resized and which are not?

Answer (score 0):

is this a control Picturebox?

```
Dim PictureBoxlist() As Picturebox = {PictureBoxPuzzlePiece1,PictureBoxPuzzlePiece2.... }

 For Each i As Picturebox In PictureBoxlist
      'stuff here
 Next
```

something like this?